# crear un sistema de desbloqueo de skins en unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

estoy intentando implementar en mi juego un sistema de compra de skins y no se como hacer para que se guarde una compra y se desbloquee la skin que ha comprado el jugador con los créditos del juego, usando el motor de Unity y programando en C#

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.